# Using greater than and less than in the same argument of a function body

Tags: r

```
my_function <- function(x){
  if (x > 10) {
    print("Higher than 10")
  } else if (x > 5 & x < 10) {
    print("Between 5 and 10")
  } else if (x < 5) {
    print("Less than 5")
  } 
}
```

I want to create a function where when I input a value it prints some text. The "higher than 10" and the "less than 5" parts work but the "between 5 and 10" bit doesn't print. What am I doing wrong in that argument?

Comment: `my_function(7)` works for me.

Comment: Yeah it works for me actually. Obviously made a mistake, thanks anyway!

Comment: There's no reason why it shouldn't work for all values that are not 5 or 10. If you don't want these values to be ignored, consider using <= or >=

Answer (score 1):

the correct function would be this:

```
my_function <- function(x){
  if (x > 10) {
    print("Higher than 10")
  } else if (x > 5) {
    print("Between 5 and 10")
  } else if (x < 5){
    print("Less than 5")
  } 
}
```

a more compact way would be by using case_when and only one print statement:

```
my_function <- function(x){
  res <- case_when(x > 10 ~ "Higher than 10",
                   x > 5 & x < 10 ~ "Between 5 and 10",
                   x < 5 ~ "Less than 5", 
                   TRUE ~ "Number is 5 or 10")
  print(res)
}
```

Note that I used a fourth condition for when the number is not within any of the ranges in the case_when

Comment: between does not include endpoints i.e. 5 and 10 is not in between 5 and 10.

Comment: @Andy I eddited my code ... thought it might me a typo as there is no treatment for 5 or 10 in the OP function

Answer (score 0):

Note that your function could be written better. For if_else statements, it should always end with an else statement instead of an if else statement.

See below as we put in 10 values from 1 to 10, it only print out 8 statements instead of 10. This is because the function does not have printouts for value 5 and 10.

```
my_function <- function(x){
  if (x > 10) {
    print("Higher than 10")
  } else if (x > 5 & x < 10) {
    print("Between 5 and 10")
  } else if (x < 5) {
    print("Less than 5")
  } 
}

for(i in 1:10) {
  my_function(i)
}

[1] "Less than 5"
[1] "Less than 5"
[1] "Less than 5"
[1] "Less than 5"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
```

A better way to write the function would be

```
my_function2 <- function(x){
  if (x >= 10) {
    print("Greater or Equal than 10")
  } else if (x > 5 & x < 10) {
    print("Between 5 and 10")
  } else {
    print("Less than or equal to 5")
  } 
}

for(i in 1:10) {
  my_function2(i)
}

[1] "Less than or equal to 5"
[1] "Less than or equal to 5"
[1] "Less than or equal to 5"
[1] "Less than or equal to 5"
[1] "Less than or equal to 5"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
[1] "Between 5 and 10"
[1] "Greater or Equal than 10"
```

Comment: between does include the endpoints now?

Comment: between is used a bit loosely in mathematical terms but the english definition would say no